# Seaborn heatmap with logarithmic y-scale (NOT colorbar)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am using the seaborn heatmap function to show a measurement varying with time and wavenumber.

e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= Z, columns = X, index = Y) # data organised into pandas dataframe.
```

Z = calculated value; X = wavenumber; Y = time.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi = 300)
sns.heatmap(df, norm = LogNorm()) # Generate heatmap

plt.yticks(ticks=[len(Y[:,1]), 0], labels=[np.floor(Y[-1,0]), 0]) # Mark value of start and end timepoint on the y-axis.
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss6R2.png): [image: Example heatmap]

I would like the y-axis to be a log scale, but simply adding

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

gives an 'math domain error'.

Most answers I can find are asking about having a logarithmic colorbar, which is not my issue here.

I'm prepared to move away from seaborn if there is something else that does this more easily.

Thanks.

Comment: As the y-axis contains 0, taking the log of 0 would generate a `math domain error`.  Seaborn only supports "categorical" heatmaps, you'd need matplotlib with e.g. `pcolormesh` to create a logscale y-axis.  Without reproducible code and test data, your question might be a bad fit for StackOverflow.